# Node.js Mongoose PUT Failed

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to PUT mongoose data using postman but it shows "TypeError: bear.save is not a function" in server console and crash the node app.

In this problem I am running two apps on different ports and db with the same code, normal http app can make all requests(POST,PUT,DEL,GET) success but another https app can't make PUT request, it can only make POST and GET successfully .

I can't understand why the same code on http app not showing error if it was code problem. Please help me.

REST API reference from - [Here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-restful-api-using-node-and-express-4)

```
.get(function(req, res) {
    Bear.find( {ID: req.params.bear_id} , function(err, bear) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);
        res.jsonp(bear);
    });
}) 

.put(function(req, res) {
    Bear.find( {ID: req.params.bear_id}, function(err, bear) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);
        bear.Name = req.body.Name;
        //res.json(bear) can send data up to this line
        // save the bear (crash after following line)
        bear.save(function(err) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);
            res.json({ message: 'Bear updated!' });
       });
 })
 });
```

Error Log on console -

```
TypeError: bear.save is not a function
at Promise.<anonymous> (/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/nodeapp.js:130:18)
at Promise.<anonymous> (/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:162:8)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at Promise.emit (events.js:188:7)
at Promise.emit (/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:79:38)
at Promise.fulfill (/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:92:20)
at /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1736:26
at model.Document.init (/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:251:11)
at completeMany (/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1734:12)
at cb (/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1697:11)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use `findOne` instead of `find`.

Comment: I am a node beginner. Thank you for your additional 3 words ;). Working perfect now.